# How to get the value of a textarea element Java?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, textarea, gettext

I'am trying to localise the xpath of an element, and then to get the content of this element (which is a text, a grey field) and compare it with the expected string.

```
<textarea _ngcontent-yjc-c213="" role="combobox" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list" nxinput="" formcontrolname="labelToDisplay" class="customer-infos cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored c-input is-disabled ng-untouched ng-pristine is-filled" disabled="true" id="nx-input-12" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="nx-autocomplete-1"></textarea>
```

so I prepared the xpath :

```
 public ObjectElements inputs = new ObjectElements("Liste of inputs", By.xpath("(//az-activities-panel//nx-formfield//textarea"));
```

And when I try to get the content of this element, it doesn't return anything.

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputs.size(); j++) {
inputs.get(i).getText();
}
```

I'm using the for because it's a list of elements with the same xpath.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the size of `inputs` list?

Comment: there is 4 fields with the same xpath, I want to check them all.

Comment: I asked about the actual size of `inputs` list you are actually getting with selenium with your code, not how many elements are on the web page matching that locator

Comment: size of inputs = 4,   but elementName = ""

Comment: I can't see any variable named `elementName` here

Comment: yes because i used the debug mode, so i found the size = 4 and the elementName of each xpath , which are all empty

Comment: I don't know what is elementName here